# NSDate returns a negative NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

I have the following code:

```
- (void)pointsStartedDisplaying {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.timeStartedDisplayingPoint = [NSDate date];
            self.stopButton.enabled = YES;

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        });
    });
}

- (void)updateElapsedTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeDisplayingPoints = [self.timeStartedDisplayingPoint timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    self.elapsedTimeValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds", elapsedTimeDisplayingPoints];
}
```

However, the value of `elapsedTimeDisplayingPoints` is perfectly accurate, except negative each time. Why does it return `-3, -4, -5,` etc?

Comment: Read the name of the method -- `timeIntervalSINCEDate`.

Comment: (And you can use `timeIntervalSinceNow` and cut out the middle man.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[If the receiver is earlier than anotherDate, the return value is negative](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a). Which is the case with your example. You can use fabs() to get a positive value.

Comment: Or, if you are measuring elapsed time, like in the example, just write `NSTimeInterval i = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];`.

Answer (score 2):

You get negative numbers because `self.timeStartedDisplayingPoint` is before `[NSDate date]`.

You need:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeDisplayingPoints = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timeStartedDisplayingPoint];
```